# How can I set unlimited retention for an compacted topic in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am struggling to get a compacted topic working as expected.

I have a compacted topic, and messages are getting properly compacted but when old messages get older than the default retention period, they get deleted.

I want a compacted topic that has at least one value for a key indefinitely.

How to accomplish that? Do I have to override the retention period for that particular compacted topic? Or should a compacted topic keep one value of a key indefinitely by default?

### My config

```
log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 1000
log.cleaner.enable = true
log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.001
log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
log.cleaner.threads = 1
log.cleanup.policy = [compact, delete]

log.retention.bytes = -1
log.retention.check.interval.ms = 5000
log.retention.hours = 0
log.retention.minutes = 20
log.retention.ms = null
```

Comment: Can you show the configuration of your compacted topic?

Comment: @MickaelMaison the issue was simply the log.cleanup.policy = [compact, delete]

Comment: This is exactly why I asked the topic config. You can have [compact, delete] set on the broker but have only compact on the topic.

Comment: @MickaelMaison can you explain what you mean by " but have only compact on the topic"? are you saying that there is a way to set log.cleanup.policy = [compact, delete] but override it to be only compact and not delete on a per topic level?

Comment: Yes exactly. The cleanup policy can be set on a per topic level. If so that takes precedence over the broker setting. You usually want the broker to have a good default, like `delete` and then on a per topic basis, you can set different policies when needed

Comment: @MickaelMaison I understand that, but i do not see a way to set [compact delete] as default, but then set topic as 'compact, and do not delete'. It is my experience that the only way to have a 'compact, and do not delete' topic, is to set default policy as 'delete' only, and set 'compact' at topic level. which is what I wrote in my answer. Am I mistaken?

Comment: When creating a topic, you can specify the cleanup policy. That works both using the `kafka-topics` tool (with `--config` flag) or via the Admin API (by setting configs on `NewTopic`). Just set it to what you want, for example `compact`. Note that topic configuration have different names than brokers configs: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found a solution that I want to share. Unfortunately, Kafka documentation is not very clear on this, so perhaps this will help someone:

Do not set this :

```
log.cleanup.policy = [compact, delete]
```

This setting will mean that all topics, are both compacted and deleted. So your topic will get compacted as per compaction rules, but when segments (messages) get older than the set retention time (in my case it was 20 min), they get deleted as well.

Set default clean up policy to:

```
log.cleanup.policy = compact
or 
log.cleanup.policy = delete
```

(log.cleanup.policy = delete is the default config)

"**log.cleanup.policy = compact**" will mean that topics, by default, will be set to be compacted.

When you set this default policy, you do not need to make any changes. There is no need to set log.retention to -1 or any other value. Your topics will be compacted and old messages never deleted (as per compaction rules)

"**log.cleanup.policy = delete**" means that topics will by default get pruned past retention time.

If you choose this default policy, then you will need to override the cleanup.policy per topic; that is, set the cleanup.policy=compact explicitly on this topic. This will turn this specific topic to use compaction, rather than delete. You do not need to adjust log.retention.

PS, Intuitively, I would think that the default "log.cleanup.policy = [compact, delete]" gets overwritten when you specify "log.cleanup.policy = compact" on per topic basis, but this is not so. With "log.cleanup.policy = [compact, delete]" you are effectively overriding how compact topics work; you change compact to be compact+delete.

PS2, if you have trouble testing and getting your topic to compact, note that only the inactive file segment can be compacted; active segment will never be compacted. So for testing, set log.segment.bytes to something small, say 10000

Comment: thx. Does ""log.cleanup.policy = compact" mean that we need infinite storage? I mean there is no cleanup process as far as I understood??

Comment: There is a KIP about compact + delete cleanup policy: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-71%3A+Enable+log+compaction+and+deletion+to+co-exist

Answer (score 8):

Choose only "compact" as the cleanup policy, and set an infinite retention.

```
log.cleanup.policy = [compact]
log.retention.bytes = -1
log.retention.ms = -1
```

Comment: Make sure that proper metrics are being collected for disk utilization before doing this