# Can I de-dupe a Kafka topic with retention.ms=-1

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Kafka topic from which I never want to purge messages.  I configured `retention.ms=-1`.  I also want the messages to be unique (by key), so I also configured `cleanup.policy=compact`.  But it appears as though those 2 configuration values will not work together.

I read somewhere once (not sure how reliable it was) that the compaction policy won't apply to times earlier than the retention time.  But that doesn't make sense since it would be purging all messages beyond the retention window, regardless of whether they are dups or not.

How do I configure my topic to have a stream of unique message (by key, which is just an incrementing number BTW) that are never purged...only de-duped?  I have messages that are 3 months old but are still have the same key value.

Kafka version 3.2.0

Comment: Could you build a KTable instead of relying on the broker to do this? There's no guarantee the topic will always have unique keys. RocksDB on the other hand, will

Comment: Can you please show an example of the data? You mention incremental numbers, so how are you generating duplicates?

Comment: Please check here, sounds like this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53231840/718849

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I don't know how dups are starting.  I'm pulling from a unique source and putting onto Kafka topics, so I presume there's a hiccup in Kafka itself (like a double-commit somehow) that'll be hard to identify or replicate.  Hence, I'm hoping the de-dupe functionality will just clean that up for me.

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel - That article lists log.compact.cleanup as the default for all topics. 
 This is not configured in our server.properties.  It also says compact.cleanup is per-topic, which is what I'm doing and is not working.  Do I need to configure log.compact.cleanup IN ADDITION to compact.cleanup?

Comment: "compact.cleanup" isn't a config in Kafka. I think you meant `log.cleanup.policy = delete` is the default... You can override `cleanup.policy=compact` per topic, yes, when they are created, or `kafka-topics --alter`

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Sorry for the confusion.  I double-checked and, yes, my topics were configured with `--config retention.ms=-1 --config max.message.bytes=20971520 --config cleanup.policy=compact`.  Since this isn't de-duping, and since that other article implies that `log.cleanup.policy=compact` won't delete past any retention time (but will de-dupe), should I try removing `retention.ms=-1` from my topic configs and only leave `cleanup.policy=compact` ?

Comment: You can remove retention, sure, but compacted cleanup policy automatically implies the time based retention is disabled. I think you should start with checking if the `log.cleaner.enabled=true` on the brokers. https://redpanda.com/guides/kafka-performance/kafka-log-compaction

Comment: @OneCricketeer - Per the Kafka release notes, this is enabled by default as of v0.9.0.1.  I confirmed that my brokers do not explicitly include this (change it to false).  Therefore, I believe it's enabled on my brokers.  Is there a log file string I can search for to confirm whether it's running and failing?

Comment: There have been old JIRA tickets that the LogCleaner thread can crash, I think you'd use JMX monitoring to check this, or maybe a heap dump... But if it is running, there should be logs, yes. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties#L42-L46